# Showing a set is well-ordered

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

Let $(C,S)$ be a well-ordered set. Let $d \notin C$.

We define the set $D=C \cup \{d\}$ and the relation $S'=S\cup (C \times \{d\})$.

Show the set $(D,S')$ is well-ordered.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Start writing and it will flow.

Comment: You need to show that every nonempty subset of $D$ contains a smallest element. There are two types of nonempty subsets of $D$.

Comment: This in an example of a "follow your nose" proof. You cannot fail, if you simply follow step by step using the standard methods of proof. (Not all proofs are like that…)

Comment: If all members of such a member were in $C$ we're done.
And go on ....

Indeed, by this definition you have adjusted $d$ as the maximum of the new set. So it won't ruin the well-orderedness property

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** This is one of those rare occasions that drawing the new order will help understanding, even to people [like me] that have hard times with drawing the situation. So the first thing is to draw the new order and understand where $d$ fits into the story.

Suppose that $A\subseteq D$ is non-empty. What happens if $A\cap C\neq\varnothing$? What happens if the intersection is empty? In either case, find a minimal element.